# JBoss Fuse: Using default Jetty port for CXF endpoints

Tags: osgi-bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am working on a CXF based web service in Jboss Fuse environment. Is it okay if I use the default org.osgi.service.http.port=8181 defined in the pax.web.cfg or should I always specify an explicit port in my cxf endpoints?

For the first option, my cxf endpoint would look like:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myWebService.endpoint"
    address="/services/WebService/1.0"
    ...
```

For the second option, it would look like:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myWebService.endpoint"
    address="http://0.0.0.0:{port}/services/WebService/1.0"
    ...
```

Is it allowed to use port 8181 for all my CXF web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally possible to use default service port for web service address. Looks like only when want to apply SSL, we should do that with httpj:engine settings for server side SSL.

[Link to Fuse HTTPS settings](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Apache_CXF_Security_Guide/files/ConfigTLS.html)